# What's the difference between a 'View' and a 'Virtual table' in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Been searching the web without success on this.

I want to store the results of a query such that I do not have to re-calculate every single time (some recalculation is permissible). The data set is large.

I have created an aggregated table based on the original data but this is of course bad practice so was investigating other potential options.

I saw SQLite allows 
Virtual Tables: https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html
as well as Views:https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

and was getting confused on what the difference between the two is (note: I know what a View is from having used SQL Server).

Comment: Did you read the pages you linked to?

Answer (score 4):

A view is defined by accessing a table and doing a projection or selection, in essence cutting out a slice of the original table, either column-wise, row-wise, or both.

A virtual table is provided to SQLite from the program using it. It is not really a "table" in the sense of a table in the database, but instead something that *looks* like a table and can be used in SQL queries as though it was. Instead it is a pluggable API where the program can plug in something that looks like a table.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think with your explanation I'm now understanding this better:

"A virtual table might represent an in-memory data structures. Or it might represent a view of data on disk that is not in the SQLite format. Or the application might compute the content of the virtual table on demand."

So the real benefits is that you're not actually store anything in the database plus it would be quicker to access?

Comment: No guarantee about quicker to access. That is entirely depending on whatever the virtual table implementation does.